# Python - Why don't mechanize sessions recognize each other?

Tags: python, session, session-cookies, mechanize

I'm running a **python** script to login to a web page using **mechanize** package. I login from **one script** and *while keeping the session aliv*e (by adding `sleep`), I access the same webpage from a **different script**. But, it asks me for the username and password even-though the first session is alive.

Why not recognize the established session? And how can I solve this?

Here is the code I'm using to **establish the session**:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from time import sleep

loginURL = '<loginURL>'
URL = '<URL>'

browser = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)

#Browser Options
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)

browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u1 Firefox/43.0')]
browser.open(loginURL)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['username'] = '<username>'
browser.form['password'] = '<password>'
login = browser.submit()
#print login.read()

print 'keeping session...'
sleep(240)
#Checking that the session still alive
open = browser.open(URL)
print open.read()
```

Then here I run the **second script**:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib    

URL = '<URL>'

browser = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)

#Browser Options
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u1 Firefox/43.0')]
#Checking the output
open = browser.open(URL)
print open.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly server recognizes logged-in user by session ID send as cookie. First script get that cookie from server (when you login) but second script has no that cookie. First script could save cookie to file and second script could read cookie from file.

**EDIT:** more precisely: both scripts can get session id but different. And server recognizes session id of first script as logged-in.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But could you please find and an explanation for my other related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993645/python-mechanize-sessions-are-not-regonized